# How can I reference a variable in a VSTS build using a string and another variable value?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm looking to reference a custom variable in VSTS using a string, and another variable's value to create the key of the variable I want.

What I have are variables specific to each environment, and I want to reference the correct one in a task. So in my screenshot, I'm trying to reference the value of the variable MobileCenter.GroupID.DEV, or MobileCenter.GroupID.QA based on whether the Environment variable is "DEV" or "QA". What I have in the screenshot doesn't seem to work.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.

It's hard to say without more context, but I think we have an X-Y problem -- you're asking how to implement Solution Y, but you should be asking how to solve Problem X.

What you *probably* want to be doing is using a Release definition instead of a build definition and breaking things down into stages of a pipeline -- you can have one for "Dev" and one for "QA", each with a different variable value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s possible to use the value of a variable to another variable.

You can use the format **`$(MobileCenter.GroupID.$(Release.EnvironmentName))`** in each of your release environment. Then you can get the value differently for different environments.

And the variable `$(Release.EnvironmentName)` is a [predefined variable](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/variables#release-variables), it can get your environment names like DEV, QA etc, so you don’t need to define it in your release definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something, look at [marina-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6936103/marina-msft)'s answer in [Is there a way to do nested variables in VSTS Release Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421772/is-there-a-way-to-do-nested-variables-in-vsts-release-management/45429792).

> The two approaches you listed can work good. And VSTS release support nested variables.
>
> Except define a variable in release definition (or environment variable) or use it directly, you can add the variable `CodeNetworkShare1=$(CodeNetworkShare.$(Release.EnvironmentName))` directly in variable group. Then in your release definition, it can use applied with different values for different environment names.