# How to replace a token with different values for different machines?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I use TFS 2018 Update 2 as CI/CD server. 
And I use [Replace Token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task as my token replacement solutions.

When I have a token A in my web.config file,
and it will be deployed to 2 VMs, VM B and VM C, by my tfs release definition.

If I need token A on VM B as Value V1 and token A on VM C as Value V2.

How to do this via Replace Tokens task?
My idea is using a powershell task to update variable A just prior to Replace Token task. Is this possible?

Please kindly provide or share your idea , it will helps me a lot.

thanks.

Comment: Are you using a Deployment Group?

Comment: Yes, I use Deployment Group

Comment: You can define the variables with the same name for different environments (Scope). Did this meet your requirement, take a look at environment variable -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#custom-variables

Comment: But I need to do this on the same enviroment. I had check my idea and it's work. If anyone have better solutions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Yes, you can use set a variable using this Powershell

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secret.Sauce;issecret=true]crushed tomatoes with garlic"
```

see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?tabs=batch&view=vsts#set-in-script).

But, you can find more convenient using Jesse's [Variable Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks).

**Option 2**

I was thinking of another technique: have the per-machine value in a variable that includes the machine name and let VSTS resolve it for you before handing to the Task. Example

In file:

```
....#(tok)#....
```

Variables:

```
tok_vma = 'v1'
tok_vmb = 'v2'
tok = $(tok_$(Agent.MachineName))
```

Nested variables are supported as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45430422/100864).
HTH

Comment: Thanks your kindly response. Nested variables is another a good idea.